# Load the same file just once HTML

Tags: javascript, html, video

Currently I'm working with html5 videos and a JavaScript slider. The thing is that as the slider should work even if there's just one slider so what I'm doing for this is to duplicate through PHP the slide so the transition remains.

The problem is that as I duplicated the video, the browser is loading the same file twice! (Remember, I duplicated so they have both the same src). Would it be possible to avoid it? I need to load the videos before starting the script as I can not have delay.

Any idea?

Comment: How are you loading the files? Do you have some code and markup. Sounds like an interesting problem.

Comment: which browser (wondering if it's a specific behavior) and does it behave the same way if you reload the page? I'm wondering if the autoload behavior in the browser isn't realizing that the asset is cachable (how large is the video)? you may be able to solve the problem this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317179/display-a-video-from-a-blob-javascript