# Mp4 from Dropbox used with HTML5 video player, is not repeating

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, dropbox

I'm working on a Squarespace website, and they don't allow video upload, so I'm using Dropbox to host a video.

The video starts playing, but he is not repeating.

This is the code:

```
<video id="htmlVideo" loop="loop">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/videoID/videoplayback.mp4?dl=1">
</video>
```

What could be the problem?

This is how I create the video

```
/* 
function repeatForDropbox() {
     console.log("repeatForDropbox caled" + htmlVideo );
 } 
 */

function createVideo() {
    var video = document.createElement("video");
        video.id = "htmlVideo";
        video.loop = "loop";

    var vidSource = document.createElement("source");  
        vidSource.type = "video/mp4";
        vidSource.src = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/videoID/videoplayback.mp4?dl=1";

    video.appendChild( vidSource );

    var vidLocation = document.querySelector('#location').parentNode;
        vidLocation.appendChild( video );
    htmlVideo = document.querySelector(" #htmlVideo "); 

    // on load, play the video/mp4
    window.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            htmlVideo.play();
            // htmlVideo.addEventListener("ended", repeatForDropbox);                                           
            // I tried here to make the video repeat, using the "ended" event listener
            // so when the video ended, the video  
            // should get another <source> element(same src)  
            // and delete the old one
            // but the event didn't fire
            // I also tried htmlVideo.onended = function() {} , but same result
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: You try to changing `loop="loop"` for: `<video loop>` ?

Comment: @Ferrrmolina, how can I do that with Javascript? To add only "loop".

Comment: I can't, because I create the <video> element using Javascript. And for the attribute "loop", I use element.loop = "loop". I also know the method element.setAttribute("loop", "") but the result is ' loop="" '

Comment: Check this: [HTML Audio/Video DOM loop Property](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_loop.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I think this attribute is not the problem because when I change the video source(a temporary link from google drive), the video is repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but I suspect this relates to redirects. A Dropbox share link with ?dl=1 on it will redirect you to a **one-time use** URL to download the content. Perhaps when the video player tries to loop, it tries to access the target of the redirect again.

This might show up in the network traffic from the browser, so it's worth taking a look. (E.g. the network tab of Chrome inspector, if you're using Chrome.)

Comment: I was afraid of that. And I think this is why the video does not repeat. What do you think about replacing the <source> element ? Will this make the video play again? Or not, because It was once called.

Answer (score 0):

I would see if squarespace will let you save the binary of the video into a text file and then import it with AJAX and save it to indexedDB before converting it to video.

Here's some links:

[Display a video from a Blob Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317179/display-a-video-from-a-blob-javascript)

https://simpl.info/video/offline/

Comment: Thanks for telling me about this possibility. Unfortunately, neither text files are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone still needs the solution, I found a workaround using jQuery:

```
$('video').on('ended', function () {
    this.load();
    this.play();
});
```

However, there is a slight delay between repeats!