# How to play a blob video in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, video, blob

I have a video named `video.mp4` I want to play it in a video/source tag in HTML, I tried too many answers from other questions and none of them worked.

```
var URL = this.window.URL || this.window.webkitURL;
var file = new Blob(["./video.mp4"], {"type": "video\/mp4"});
var value = URL.createObjectURL(file);

console.log(value);
video.src = value;
```

When I tried the code above it printed a blob, but when I want to play the video it doesn't work and shows this error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.

The same thing happens when trying the answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14317179/20073119)

Comment: use iframe and not img tag

Comment: @YasserCHENIK how can i use it?

Comment: `video` must be an element of the tag iframe and that's all

Comment: from this line `video.src = value;`

Comment: Related question: [Failed to load because no supported source was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674223/domexception-failed-to-load-because-no-supported-source-was-found)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react you could use package reactPlayer for the same and play the video.

```
<ReactPlayer playing url='video1.mp4'
                height='500px'
                width='800px'
                controls='true'
            />
```

Otherwise if you want to play from blob then:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"; 
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

 const [videoFilePath, setVideoFilePath] = useState(null);


const handleVideoUpload = (event) => {
setVideoFilePath(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
};
....

<input type="file" onChange={handleVideoUpload} />
...

<ReactPlayer url={videoFilePath} width="100%" height="100%" controls={true} />
```